# gráfico con variable temporal

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy intentando crear un gráfico a partir de un df similar al siguiente:

```
Fecha   Peso (kg)
12/01/2023  64,1
16/02/2023  64,8
07/03/2023  66,2
03/04/2023  66,8
04/05/2023  65,7
05/06/2023  66,8
03/07/2023  66,4
01/08/2023  66,2
04/09/2023  65,2
02/10/2023  65,5
06/11/2023  65,7
11/12/2023  64,4
```

Intento generar un gráfico con:

```
peso <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Fecha, y = Peso_kg)) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(64, 67, by = 0.5))
```

Y me sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que cada medida del gráfico coincida en el tick de mes y año independientemente del día en que se haya tomado, y que me salgan todos los meses del año.

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, lo que podrías hacer es modificar tu `dataframe` y eliminar el día o asignarles a todas las fechas el primer día del mes.

Comment: Hola, a ambos. Sí, al final he lo que comentáis los dos. He extraído el mes y me he generado una nueva variable con la fecha a día 1. Pero esperaba que hubiese una forma más directa que no implicase modificar el df. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la fecha tiene siempre el mismo formato y no la necesitas para hacer algún otro calculo, puedes recortar el mes y el año con `substr(Fecha, 4, 10)`. También te sugiero que uses `group = 1` para no tener problemas con el `geom_line()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = substr(Fecha, 4, 10), y = Peso_kg, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(64, 67, by = 0.5)) +
  labs(
    x = "Fecha",
    y = "Peso (Kg)"
  )
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Tal y como indica @HeytalePazguato, convendría transformar los datos antes de realizar el gráfico.

```
# Cargar librería para trabajar con fechas
  library(lubridate)
# Dar formato fecha a "Fecha"
  df$Fecha <- as.Date(df$Fecha, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
# Extraer el mes
  df$Mes <- month(df$Fecha)
```

En principio el mes te lo determinará en su forma numérica, si deseas obtener el texto correspondiente deberás realizar una transformación.

Utilizando tu propio código, simplemente reemplazando "Fecha" por "Mes" obtendrías el gráfico deseado:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Mes, y = Peso_kg)) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(64, 67, by = 0.5))
```